# Tooltip content from database

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page which displays the names of friends for the corresponding user. When I mouse over a particular name, the other details like ph number, mail id should be displayed as tool tip. The flow is like this.

1. User logs in.
2. Names of his friends are accessed from the bean(which in turn fetches details from database) and displayed
3. User hovers on each friend's name.
4. Tool tip with friend's details is displayed.

This is  how I get friend's details.

```
<td width="200px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <font color="RED" face="Arial,sans-serif" SIZE="2" id="<%=val%>"> <%=numbers[0].substring(1,numbers[0].length())%>
   </font>
</td>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: these p tags are static or dynamic..If its dynamic then it is possible

Comment: calling `tooltip()` isn't going to magically create a tooltip for you... where does this function come from? are you using jQuery UI? If so, have you looked at [the documentation at all](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer content from p tags are dynamic.

Comment: Which framework you are using..

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer what is a framework?

Comment: Java with MVC architecture.

Answer (score 1):

used this code :

Check Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/XZWhJ/13/)

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$( document ).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

[image: Tested]

Comment: How do I load dynamic content in tooltip?

Comment: give each tooltip has seprate id and load dynamic content in tooltip